# Error computing aggregate over related model in Django

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    id_contest = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Registration(models.Model):
    id_registration = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='registrations',
        related_query_name='registration')
    contest = models.ForeignKey(
        Contest,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='registrations',
        related_query_name='registration')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    confirmed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Submission(models.Model):
    id_submission = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='submissions',
        related_query_name='submission')
    contest = models.ForeignKey(
        Contest,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='submissions',
        related_query_name='submission')
    submitted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_valid = models.NullBooleanField()
    public_score = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

And I'm working on a leaderboard query (PostgreSQL) like:

```
select 
    r.team_id,
    max(t.username) as team_name,
    count(s.team_id) as num_submissions,
    min(s.public_score) as score,
    max(s.submitted_at) as last_submission,
    max(r.confirmed_at) as confirmation
from api_registration r
left join auth_user t on (r.team_id = t.id)
left join api_submission s on (r.contest_id = s.contest_id and s.team_id = t.id and s.is_valid = TRUE)
where r.contest_id = 1
group by r.team_id
order by score ASC, last_submission DESC;
```

Which returns the results I want.
However, when translating into Django QuerySet operations, the closest I've 
come is:

```
leaderboard = Registration.objects \
              .filter(contest=contest, contest__submission__is_valid=True) \
              .annotate(team_name=Max('team__username'),
                        num_submissions=Count('team__submission'),
                        score=Min('contest__submission__public_score'),
                        last_submission=Max('contest__submission__submitted_at'),
                        confirmation=Max('confirmed_at')) \
              .order_by('score', '-last_submission')
```

which generates the query:

```
SELECT
"api_registration"."id_registration",
"api_registration"."team_id",
"api_registration"."contest_id",
"api_registration"."created_at",
"api_registration"."confirmed_at",
MAX("api_registration"."confirmed_at") AS "confirmation",
MAX("api_submission"."submitted_at") AS "last_submission",
MAX("auth_user"."username") AS "team_name",
MAX("api_submission"."public_score") AS "score",
COUNT(T5."id_submission") AS "num_submissions"
FROM "api_registration" INNER JOIN "api_contest" ON ("api_registration"."contest_id" = "api_contest"."id_contest")
INNER JOIN "api_submission" ON ("api_contest"."id_contest" = "api_submission"."contest_id")
INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("api_registration"."team_id" = "auth_user"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "api_submission" T5 ON ("auth_user"."id" = T5."team_id")
WHERE ("api_registration"."contest_id" = 1
AND "api_submission"."is_valid" = True)
GROUP BY "api_registration"."id_registration"
ORDER BY "score" ASC, "last_submission" DESC;
```

And doesn't properly compute the correct number of submissions per team.
Any help on how to define the Django QuerySet operations to obtain correct results?

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:`num_submissions=Count('team__submission'),` for `num_submissions=Count('team_id'),`.

This is to group according to the team_id of the table registration.

Comment: It's returning the same value for num_submissions for a team without submissions.
I've updated the desired SQL query, which now returns correct results when there are more than one team, and allows retrieving teams without submissions